# EJB2.x deployment issue on jboss7

Tags: deployment, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-2.x

I have an application containing ejb2.x and ejb3.0  it is running on jboss5.1 .When we migrate with few changes in configuration and jndi it gives the following error at the time of deployment

```
11:42:16,884 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."intlwmiejb_.txt.jar".INSTALL: org.j boss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."intlwmiejb_.txt.jar".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "intlwmiejb_.txt.jar"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40] Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011030: Could not configure component AdminDomainManager
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:92)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 5 more Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014522: Could not find method public abstract boolean javax.ejb.EJBObject.isIdentica l(javax.ejb.EJBObject) throws java.rmi.RemoteException from view com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManager on EJB class AdminDomainManager
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.session.SessionBeanObjectViewConfigurator.configure(SessionBeanObjectViewConfigurator.java:108)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:921)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
        ... 6 more   jndi shown on server.log is   14:42:23,647 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named AdminDomainManager in deployment unit subdeployment "intlwmiejb.jar" of deployment "wmi.ear" are as follows: java:global/wmi/intlwmiejb/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManagerLocalHome java:app/intlwmiejb/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManagerLocalHome java:module/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManagerLocalHome java:global/wmi/intlwmiejb/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManager java:app/intlwmiejb/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManager java:module/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManager java:jboss/exported/wmi/intlwmiejb/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManager java:global/wmi/intlwmiejb/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManagerHome java:app/intlwmiejb/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManagerHome java:module/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManagerHome java:jboss/exported/wmi/intlwmiejb/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManagerHome java:global/wmi/intlwmiejb/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManagerLocal java:app/intlwmiejb/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManagerLocal java:module/AdminDomainManager!com.intertel.wmi.ejb.auth.AdminDomainManagerLocal
```

Comment: This smells a bit like you have some jars containing Java EE APIs in your deployment

Comment: @SteveC : Yes jars contains Java EE API,

Comment: You should get rid of all jars containing JavaEE APIs and implementations otherwise you may see the behaviour you see above

Comment: @SteveC, thanks Steve...!